# Help with GCC compile in C89

Tags: gcc

I have to compile code in C89 for class, I wrote this code to see if it would compile. I compile it using,

> gcc -std=c89 -pedantic

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("%p", &number);
}
```

this code would compile just fine on a system with gcc version 4.1.2, but on a machine with version 5.3(Ubuntu 5.3), it would give me the error

> warning:format '%p' expects argument of type 'void *', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]

If anyone can give me a work around I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Are you actually using format specifier `%d` or `%p`? Are you trying to print the value or the address of `number`?

Comment: I am trying to get the address

Comment: my mistake i meant to put %p

Comment: Really this isn't a question about Ubuntu.  It isn't a question about any Linux operating system.  You'd be getting this with the same GCC on a BSD, or on Windows.  This is a pure programming language question.

Comment: @Sil , gcc 4.1 that old compiler how did you get and  which release you are using?

Answer (score 2):

%p expects a void *, so casting to void * will do the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("%p", (void *)&number);
}
```